# cannot cherry-pick a commit that needs an edit

Tags: git, commit, git-cherry-pick

I can cherry-pick a commit without issues, however I need to edit the commit message , here is the command I used with error that I get.

```
$ git cherry-pick 05f8ab05be965ed05c6drtad237a0oi6f607b71c -e "ticket-548 My cars Module"
fatal: bad revision 'SCOS-818 My cars Module'
```

Comment: `-e` / `--edit` does not take an argument. You told Git to cherry pick two commits, one named `05f8ab...` and one named `SCOS-818 My...`, with the option to edit each commit's commit-message.

Comment: if it does not take an argument how can you cherry pick a commit and use -e to edit your message then?

Comment: `-e` means: *do the cherry-pick(s) and fire up the editor on the commit message*. You edit the commit message *after* your editor has fired up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `git commit --amend` after your cherry-pick will allow you to change the commit message.